# Insert Data into Form oracle apex

Tags: oracle, process, oracle-apex, sql-insert

I am trying to insert data into a read only form using following sql query in the pre-rendering page process:
begin

```
select s.ID, s.SPID, s.PHONE_NUMBER
INTO :P9_ID,:P9_SPID,:P9_PHONE_NUMBER
FROM TABLE1 s
left outer join TABLE2 f on f.ID=s.ID
where f.ID=:P9_TBL2_ID;
end;
```

However I always get the error no data found when using the where clause, although the page element has an explicit value (here number 5).

Modifying the where clause to:

```
where f.ID=5;
```

I get the right data inserted into the read only form.

In general the question is, how can data been loaded into a form from table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> although the page element has an explicit value (here number 5).

How did `:P9_TBL2_ID` item get its value? It isn't enough just to *see it* on the screen - it has to be put into session state. We usually do it by submitting the page.

However, as it is a pre-rendering process, you must somehow be coming to that page - I presume from some other page. Usual way to do that is to push a button which redirects to another page. Its properties allow you to **set items** on the target page (`P9` in your case) with some values (`5` in your case). So, did you do that? If so, it *should work* properly.

Comment: The value of :P9_TBL2_ID is set by an SQL query in the default range. And yes the page is redirected from another page

Comment: Ok, you were right, I did not set a value once the page was submitted.
I changed this in the branching process and set the corresponding page elements in Set Items.
But one question remains and that is that I would like to forward to the same page but this time from a different person.
However, the branching process is slightly different for this other person, the page is determined by the Behaviour URL Identified by Item(Redirect). This means that I cannot have a Set Items area here and therefore I get the error No Data found.

Comment: Then create URL yourself (see GET_URL function https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/GET_URL-Function.htm#AEAPI30190) and use it instead.

Comment: So I changed now the url to apex_page.get_url(p_page => branch_page,p_items=>:P8_ID); , I now get the error ERR-1002 Unable to find item ID for item "5"(this is the value I am passing)...Do I have to store this value somehow in the target page?

Comment: Based on what you posted, you're supposed to pass that value to page 9, into P9_TBL2_ID item.

Comment: Thank you @Littlefoot:) I have noticed that this question does not relate to the above question and that the above question has actually already been answered.
For the issue with the URL, I will create a new question in which I can better describe the issue.